# EventCalendar table bulider is not installing in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

I am having problem in full_calendar table builder.and i am using rails 4.I have used following command . **rails plugin install git://github.com/p8/table_builder.git
** I got error like **/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@ruby2/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require': cannot load such file -- rails/commands/plugin (LoadError)
**
And My view look like

[image]

It won't showing in table format. Please help me....

Answer (score 0):

Use the gem instead of the plugin.  Also I don't think that repository is active anymore, there is an alternative listed on the readme; and it doesn't look like table_builder has been updated for rails 4 so you might encounter other issues.

This is the updated repo: https://github.com/watu/table_builder

Add it to your gemfile & run bundle install:

```
gem "watu_table_builder", :require => "table_builder"
```

If you're using a tutorial for an older version of rails note that there are some things that will bite you -- (plugins, strong paramenters, Model.all, etc)

Comment: After adding gem "watu_table_builder", :require => "table_builder".it shows error like "superclass mismatch for class Calendar"  and it shows error in line class Calendar < Struct.new(:view, :date, :callback)